# Tensorflow saver.restore() not restoring my model checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've seen this issue brought up a few times on StackOverflow, but none of the solutions have helped me.

I've trained an actor-critic reinforcement learning network in `tensorflow.compat.v1`, and am using the `saver.save()` function throughout training to save the model files as it goes, so I end up with the `.index`, `.meta` and `.data` files. Using Python 3.6 in Windows.

Now in a second script, I want to reload this model that uses the exact same architecture and dataset, but when I run it, I get completely different results, which I think tells me I'm not loading the model properly. Note, I'm using `self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()` so I'm not running it within a `with sess` loop.

So in the training script, I reference my Actor and Critic networks and begin the session:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
self.actor = Actor("actor-original", self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE)
self.actor_target = Actor("actor-target", self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE)
self.critic = Critic("critic-original", self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE, self.LEARNING_RATE)
self.critic_target = Critic("critic-target", self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE, self.LEARNING_RATE)
self.grad_critic = tf.gradients(self.critic.logits, self.critic.Y)
self.actor_critic_grad = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.OUTPUT_SIZE])
weights_actor = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="actor")
self.grad_actor = tf.gradients(self.actor.logits, weights_actor, -self.actor_critic_grad)
grads = zip(self.grad_actor, weights_actor)
self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.LEARNING_RATE).apply_gradients(grads)  # Adam optimizer

self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  # Start the session
self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Then I use the `saver.save()` function below during training when certain metrics are met:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)
save_path = saver.save(self.sess, "./model_checkpoint_files"))
```

Now, in my secondary script, I want to reload this model. So far, what I have is this:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
self.actor = Actor("actor-original", self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE)
self.actor_target = Actor("actor-target", self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE)
self.critic = Critic("critic-original", self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE, self.LEARNING_RATE)
self.critic_target = Critic("critic-target", self.state_size, self.OUTPUT_SIZE, self.LAYER_SIZE, self.LEARNING_RATE)
self.grad_critic = tf.gradients(self.critic.logits, self.critic.Y)
self.actor_critic_grad = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.OUTPUT_SIZE])
weights_actor = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope="actor")
self.grad_actor = tf.gradients(self.actor.logits, weights_actor, -self.actor_critic_grad)
grads = zip(self.grad_actor, weights_actor)
self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.LEARNING_RATE).apply_gradients(grads)  # Adam optimizer

self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  # Start the session
#self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
#saver = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph("./model_checkpoint_files.meta")
saver.restore(self.sess, "./model_checkpoint_files")
#self.sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer()) # tf.initialize_all_variables() # tf.local_variables_initializer() # tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

As you can see, I've tried some different combinations of model loading to try and get this working. Further on in my second script, I just call the `self.sess.run()` to get the best action.

Does anyone see anything that I'm missing? Just looking to load the model and use it on the same dataset to get repeatable results. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The more I'm reading about this, I'm thinking the reason is because some values aren't being saved using the `tf.saver()` function, and what I should be doing is using the `saved_model()` function as it also saves the values of the variables used in the training? Using my sample code above, how might I go about implementing that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you create a new `session` when you restore the model with `self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  # Start the session`. The `session` used by a `Saver` to save a model should be the same as the one to restore the model, since a `tensorflow` graph lives inside a `session`.

Here is a working example that you can modify

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 

tf.reset_default_graph()

class Model():

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.x = tf.placeholder('float32',shape=[None,1])
        self.y = tf.placeholder('float32',shape=[None,1])
        
        self.w1 = tf.get_variable('w1',initializer=tf.zeros([1, 20]))
        self.b1 = tf.get_variable('b1',initializer=tf.zeros([20]))
        self.w2 = tf.get_variable('w2',initializer=tf.zeros([20, 1]))
        self.b2 = tf.get_variable('b2',initializer=tf.zeros([1]))
        
        self.y1 = tf.matmul(self.x, self.w1) + self.b1
        self.y2 = tf.matmul(self.y1, self.w2) + self.b2
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.y - self.y2))
        
        self.train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(self.loss)
        
        self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
        
    def train(self,x_train,y_train):
        
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for iter in range(100):
            for _ in range(10):
                batch_xs, batch_ys = x_train[_*10:(_+1)*10][:,None],y_train[_*10:(_+1)*10][:,None]
                self.sess.run(self.train_step, feed_dict={self.x: batch_xs, self.y: batch_ys})
            if iter == 50:
                self.saver.save(self.sess, 'tmp/model.ckpt')
                self.inside_val = self.sess.run(self.loss, feed_dict={self.x:x_train[:,None],self.y:y_train[:,None]})
                
        print(self.sess.run(self.loss, feed_dict={self.x:x_train[:,None],self.y:y_train[:,None]}))

    def test(self,x_test,y_test):
        print(self.sess.run(self.loss, feed_dict={self.x: x_test[:,None], self.y: y_test[:,None]}))
        
    def reload(self,model_path,x_test,y_test):
        self.saver.restore(self.sess, model_path)
        return self.sess.run(self.loss, feed_dict={self.x: x_test[:,None], self.y: y_test[:,None]})
        
        
x_train = np.linspace(1, 6, 101)
y_train = 2 * x_train + 3 + 0.1 * np.random.random(101)

m = Model()
m.train(x_train,y_train)
# test
m.test(x_train,y_train)

try:
    assert m.inside_val == m.reload('tmp/model.ckpt',x_train,y_train)
    print('checked')
except AssertionError:
    print('The values are different.')
```

Running this script, you will find the trained model is successfully restored.

Comment: Thanks! I'll play with this a little later, I was stumped, but I think this will help.

Comment: Still might need some clarification on how to get this to work as it doesn't seem to be working for me still. Wondering if you'd be able to assist some more? I'm trying to essentially restore the session/model/variables (and whatever else needs reloading in a Tensorflow session, I still don't understand it all), from a new script, not within the same training script, so that I can recreate repeatable results. If I threw my project into a Colab notebook, would you be able to take a look and tell me what you see???